# Delete Rows prior to specific String in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have  excel files in following format:

```
Sensor 1 meta
Sensor 2 meta
"Summary of Observation"
Sensor 1
Sensor 2
```

The number of rows before and after "Summary of Observation" is not fixed (i.e one file may have only sensor 1,2 while other may have 1,2,3....)

In dataframe, I only want information after "Summary of Observation")

Right now, I open the excel file, note the row from which I want information and parse it in

```
df = pd.read_excel("1.xlsx",skiprows = %put some value here%)
```

Is there a way to automate this, i.e. I don't want to open excel. Rather only import relevant rows (or delete them after importing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After importing the file you can find `index` and select a data from that point.

```
# I used column name as `text` you can replace it with yours
idx = df[df['text']=='Summary of Observation'].index[0]

df = df[idx+1:]
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                    text                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
3                Sensor 1                                                                                                             
4                Sensor 2
```

Or if you want to include *Summary of Observation* just use `idx` in place of `idx+1`

Answer (score 1):

you can open the excel and use `df.loc[df[0]=="Summary of Observation"].index[0]` to get the index
Working code at https://github.com/gklc811/Python3.6/blob/master/stackoverflowsamples/excel.ipynb